# Advances in? Advances on? (Noun)

Tags: prepositions

I'm wondering which expression is grammatically correct or natural:

1. Recent advances in computer graphics
2. Recent advances on computer graphics

It seems that both usages appear in a dictionary, but I was not sure how to determine which one is more appropriate to use in a web article.

Comment: "in" is correct. "on" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman is right.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/advance) has many examples of the correct usage of 'advance' (under **NOUN**):

> 1 A forward movement.
>
> *‘the rebels' advance on Madrid was well under way’*
>
> 2 A development or improvement.
>
> *‘genuine advances in engineering techniques’*

It is the second usage that you need.

Comment: Thank you! In the future, I can refer to that site! I will use "in".